# i want to use chrome console to click on any facebook post reaction button ex, love , wow , sad, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools, facebook-like

On Facebook, I can click on the **like** button of every post using the chrome console because it has a specific class name. However, if I want to click on any other reaction button (e.g. **love, haha, wow, sad**, etc..) I can't: all of them have the same class name and they need the mouse to hover over them. How can I get to click on these buttons?

thanks <3

At the moment, to click the like button I use the code `document.getElementsByClassName('_6rk2 img sp_ddXiTdIB8vm sx_44a25c')[0].click();`. It doesn't work for the other buttons.

thanks again <3

Comment: You could loop on all likes, since you know the class, then, for each element, trigger a hover event, wait until the reactions popup comes out, click on the desired reaction (identifying its class), and so on. Be careful, facebook doesn't like bot actitudes

Comment: Also, find a way to identify the buttons without using those cryptic class names, because they can change anytime the website code base is updated.